# X Server for Windows that will run from memory stick

Tags: windows, remote-access

I have a corporate laptop (Windows 7) that has restrictive permissions as far as installing ad hoc software packages.  I need to be able to remotely use a Linux desktop (Ubuntu), and for a secure shell package PuTTY is usable (it runs just as an executable from a personal directory).

Getting an X Server that I can forward X traffic to is more difficult, simply because of the size of the package (number of files).  I'm thinking about installing an X Server on a USB memory stick, hoping that one can be found to run that way.

Several sites offer modified Xming packages that claim to do this.  Does anyone have a recommendation from personal experience that will supply an X Server running from memory stick?

Comment: @Olli why is this off topic? An X Server is software, is it not?

Comment: This question is **not** off topic. I had really poorly worded comment that I already deleted. I was trying to say that "This does not answer your question, but you probably shouldn't circumvent restrictions of your corporate laptop".

Comment: @Olli: To put it constructively, I need something of this kind to *abide* by corporate restrictions.  You have my word on that.

Comment: I wonder if removing the corporate part of it makes it a 'better' question. Lots of folk have to run things in limited accounts, or choose to, and its the same question without it.

Comment: @hardmath I am looking for the identical requirements as you. Do let me know if you found something.

Comment: @krishnakumarG: I did find something, but after four years it's a bit hazy.  My best guess is that I settled on [Xming + PuTTY](http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/) running from a memory stick on Windows.  If I can dredge up more details, I'll post an Answer.

Comment: @hardmath `xming` is not open source.

Comment: @krishnakumarG: While open source is not mentioned in the Question (and I'm not sure I understand your Comment), downloads from the Project Xming Sourceforge repository [are considered Public Domain](http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/terms.php).  If you have a concern, maybe my posting an Answer will help address it.

Answer (score 3):

I've recommended [mobaxterm](http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/) in the past and I'd do it again here - its a nice little precompiled package of cygwin based tools that includes a bash shell, with tabs (which you can use for text mode SSH), xserver and quite a few other useful things. You can either run local X apps on it, X forward a single application, or an entire desktop using XDMCP.

They have demos on their site (which are annoyingly not linkable here) of what it can do and there are many first and third party plugins including older versions of X11 and mosh.

The basic version is free, and there's no limits on the features you need there (the paid version has tftp, http and ftp servers as well).

The portable version is less than 20MB so it probably fits your needs perfectly.

Comment: Do you think this answer would be better if it were rewritten with dot points? (I do)

Comment: Not really my writing style, and he only needs one feature of many, IMO

Comment: I would post my own recommendations for mobaxterm (with dot points), however I never bothered to get X11 working

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Although not a requirement of the OP, I'd like to point out `mobaxterm` is not open-source.

Comment: Can you get mobaxterm to not precompile everything on its won, ?